# dynamically change id of input field when click the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `div`, and in that `div` I have form like two input fields with respective id's, like the one shown below:

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            var $div = $('div[id^="div"]:last');
            var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
            var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'div'+num );
            $div.after( $klon);

        });
    }); 
    </script>
    <body>
    <button type = "button" id = "btn1" >submit </button>
    <div id = "div1">
    <h4><b>Trace 1 </b></h4>
      <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="t1_x_axis" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="t1_y_axis" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
  </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Here my query is when click the button I need to display this `div` along with form, how many times I click that button that many times the `div` will display one by one *with different id in div and two input field id* also should change.

For instance if I click the button 5 times it should display 5 times and those `div` id and field id should be different

Expected output:

```
 Trace 1
       X axis:   
       Y axis:
    Trace 1
       X axis: 
       Y axis:
    Trace 1
       X axis: 
       Y axis:
    Trace 1
       X axis: 
       Y axis:
    Trace 1
       X axis: 
       Y axis:
```

Comment: please share complete structure of the table and submitbtn function

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: i have done here i am  able to change div id dynamically when i click the button but i am unable change those two field id's ,Thanks .

Comment: All you've shown is your HTML. Remember that SO is for helping you debug code, not to write it for you. As such please edit the question to include the JS you've written so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Ya ,i have added my complete code .kindly check once .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution ever... but it works in your case. I used `attr("id", "newId")`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            var $div = $('div[id^="div"]:last');
            var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
            var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'div'+num );

            $klon.find('input:first').attr("id", "xAxis_test");
            $klon.find('input:last').attr("id", "yAxis_test");

            $div.after( $klon);

        });
    });
```

Or:

```
        $klon.find("input[name='t1_x_axis']").attr("id", "xAxis_test");
        $klon.find("input[name='t1_y_axis']").attr("id", "xAxis_test");
```

Comment: Hi @karlan ,when I click `submit` button those divs are cloning so is there any possible to get those div input fields Id's in alert box ,like if click `submit` button it will display 2nd div input fields so those input field Id i want to show in alert box ,if i click 3rd time `submit` button it will display 3rd div input fields so those input field Id's only i want to show in alert box ,could you please help me.

Comment: ```var divIdX="xAxis_"
            var divIdY="yAxis_"

            $klon.find("input[name='t1_x_axis']").attr("id", divIdX + num )
            $klon.find("input[name='t1_y_axis']").attr("id", divIdY + num);

            $div.after( $klon);
            alert("X Axis: " + divIdX + num + "\n" + "Y Axis: " + divIdY + num);```

Comment: Maybe not very clear but above code is new code after ```var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'div'+num );```